# Add script on button click and call its method

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to dynamically add a script (it's a chat window) on button click and call a method from that script.

Here's the code I have achieved so far:

```js
const callExternalScript = url => {
  let script
  script = document.querySelector(`script[src="${url}"]`)

  if (!script) {
    script = document.createElement('script')
    script.type = 'application/javascript'
    script.src = url
    script.async = true
    document.body.appendChild(script)
  }


  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    script.addEventListener('load', function() {
      res()
    })
    script.addEventListener('error', function() {
      rej('error')
    })
  })
}

const handleClick = () => {
  callExternalScript('http://abcd.js')
    .then(() => {
      abc() // method from abcd js;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

```html
<button onClick="handleClick()">Click Me</button>
```

I got two issues with this code:

1. This code works on the first-time load of the script. It doesn't work if the script is already loaded.
2. abc method doesn't run as abcd script calls another script internally with this abc method and the code doesn't wait for that to load.

Comment: I think you can solve 2 by not using `async`

Comment: For 1, if the script is already loaded, return a promise that just calls `res()` instead of using the event listener.

Comment: Ohh thanks @Barmar, For 1, is it right way to just return promise with res()?
For 2, I didn't get what you are suggesting here.

Comment: Don't do `script.async = true`

Answer (score 0):

If you make the script asynchronous, the `load` event runs when the script is fetched from the server, but doesn't wait for the code in it to execute, so `abcd()` won't be defined when you try to call it. Remove `script.async = true;` to solve that problem.

If the script tag is found, the script is already loaded, so adding a `load` event listener doesn't do anything. In that case you should return a promise that resolves immediately.

```js
const callExternalScript = url => {
  let script
  script = document.querySelector(`script[src="${url}"]`)

  if (!script) {
    script = document.createElement('script')
    script.type = 'application/javascript'
    script.src = url
    // script.async = true
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      script.addEventListener('load', function() {
        res()
      })
      script.addEventListener('error', function() {
        rej('error')
      })
    })
  }

  return new Promise((res, rej) => res());
}

const handleClick = () => {
  callExternalScript('http://abcd.js')
    .then(() => {
      abc() // method from abcd js;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

```html
<button onClick="handleClick()">Click Me</button>
```